# How to redraw an ncurses menu

Tags: c++, c, menu, ncurses

I am working on an ncurses-based tool that has 4 tiled windows with a command bar at the bottom of the screen.  The windows form a 2x2 grid like this:

```
+----+----------------+
| 1  |  2             |
+----+----------------+
| 3  |  4             |
|    |                |
|    |                |
|    |                |
+----+----------------+
```

The top left is fixed in size, so when the app is resized, 2 changes in width, 3 changes in height, and 4 changes in both directions.

I had the redrawing code working fine until I started putting menus (using menu.h) in window 4.  Now, if i resize the window too small, part of the menu will get cut off, but when you make the window bigger again, it does not repaint what was removed.  Doing a post_menu() in the redraw code does not repaint it.

What is the proper way to repaint a menu?  Do I have to dispose of it and recreate it from scratch every time?  I do have logic in my code that only repaints if necessary (data changed, window resized, etc), so it would not be creating a new menu every cycle for no reason, but this still seems a bit heavy handed.  There has to be a simple way to just redraw the menu you have already created.  What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreating the structure is the simplest way.

The form and menu libraries use an abstraction of the keys you type.  That abstraction does not include a resize feature.

You *could* run `wresize` for each of the windows in the menu, e.g., these lines from `menu.h`

```
  WINDOW        *win;                   /* Window containing menu          */
  WINDOW        *sub;                   /* Subwindow for menu display      */
  WINDOW        *userwin;               /* User's window                   */
  WINDOW        *usersub;               /* User's subwindow                */
```

but making that work requires some study of the library.  There's an example which resizes a *form* in [ncurses-examples](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html) (named `cardfile`), but no analogous example for *menus*.

Further reading:

- [`wresize` - resize a curses window](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/wresize.3x.html)
- [`is_term_resized`,  `resize_term`,  `resizeterm`  -  change  the
     curses terminal size](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html)

Comment: So whenever the menu needs to be redrawn, call free_item() for each item, free_menu() for the menu, and recreate the whole thing?  Oh, and if you care, grab the index of the currently selected item so you can set it back after you recreate it.  Thanks.